# How to Compare two different tables based on multiple columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The first table consists of Accounts with State and Country information which are mostly correct with few wrong rows:

```
ID       Account       State         Country      Text
1001      Acc1          NJ           USA
1002      Acc2          NY           Null
1003      Acc3          Texas        Japan
```

And I have the second table which has the correct state and Country information to which the first tables needs to be compared to:

```
ID         State          Country
1          NJ              USA
2          NY              USA
3          Texas           USA
```

The query should check:

1. If the state in the first table exists in the second table and
2. Is it associated with the correct country.

If both the above conditions are satisfied, the first table's Text column should get updated with the state value.
If any of the two conditions are not satisfied, the text column should remain blank.So the result should look like this:

```
ID      Account      State     Country       Text
1001     Acc1         NJ         USA          NJ
1002     Acc2         NY         USA           
1003     Acc3         Texas      USA
```

I am able to check whether both the conditions are satisfied, also I am able to get the rows which doesn't satisfy the condition. However, I am not sure how to go forward and update the table with the correct state. Any help would very much appreciated.

Comment: Well, what does your current query look like and how have you tried to write your update statement?

Comment: The Query I am using to find the rows which are incorrect in the first table is:       select f.* from firstTable f
FULL JOIN SecondTable s
ON f.State = s.State and f.Country = s.Country
WHERE f.State IS NOT NULL AND ( s.Country_Code IS NULL OR s.State IS NULL ). However, i am not sure how to go about performing the upgrade on the same table for correct rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this.

```
UPDATE T1
SET 
    [Text] = (CASE WHEN T1.Country = T2.Country THEN T1.[State] ELSE NULL END)
    , Country = (CASE WHEN T1.Country = T2.Country THEN T1.Country ELSE T2.Country END) 
FROM TableAccounts T1
INNER JOIN TableCountry T2 ON T1.[State] = T2.[State]
```

Answer (score 4):

These queries will work with MSSQL to drive an update in either direction...

```
SELECT State, Country FROM t1
EXCEPT
SELECT State, Country FROM t2

SELECT State, Country FROM t2
EXCEPT
SELECT State, Country FROM t1

t1 is this in your post: (ID,Account,State,Country,Text)
t2 is this in your post: (ID,State,Country)
```